# How can I remove a row of a matrix according to the last element?

Tags: list-manipulation, dataset

I have a set of data in the form $$\{x,y,f(x,y),\rm error\}.$$ I want to remove the row which has the largest value of error. I thought it would be possible to use `DeleteCases`, but I was not able to do that. How can I figure it out?

Here is my set of data

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];

data = {
{16, 11, 12, 0.002},
{15, 12, 22, 0.012},
{14, 13, 22, 0.022},
{13, 14, 32, 0.032},
{12, 15, 42, 0.042},
{11, 16, 52, 0.052}
};
```

Comment: Deleting the data point with the maximal error sounds like a potentially problematic practise to me

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One way would be to first find the row with maximal error and then use that to make an expression to be used in DeleteCases.

```
MaximalBy[data, Last]
(*{{11, 16, 52, 0.052}}*)
```

Notice that a list of maximal elements was returned, so we'll have to massage this a bit.

```
DeleteCases[data, Alternatives @@ MaximalBy[data, Last]]
```

Now, this raises an interesting question. What do you want to happen if there are multiple elements with the same maximal error. What I've shown above will remove all of them. If you just want one of them, you could do

```
DeleteCases[data, First@MaximalBy[data, Last]]
```

If there are further criteria for determining which maximal element should be deleted, then you'll need to inject the selection criteria.

Answer (score 6):

```
ClearAll[f]

f = Cases[{__, Except @ Max @ #[[All, -1]]}] @ # &;

f @ data
```

> ```
> {{16, 11, 12, 0.002}, {15, 12, 22, 0.012}, {14, 13, 22, 0.022}, 
>  {13, 14, 32, 0.032}, {12, 15, 42, 0.042}}
> ```

Answer (score 6):

This removes exactly one row, even in the case of ties, and is efficient:

```
Drop[data, Ordering[data[[All, -1]], -1]]
(*
{{16, 11, 12, 0.002},
 {15, 12, 22, 0.012},
 {14, 13, 22, 0.022},
 {13, 14, 32, 0.032},
 {12, 15, 42, 0.042}}  
*)
```

Alternatively, use `data[[All, 4]]` if the error is in the 4th column, but not the last column (that is, if you're data is not like the OP's).

The above performs well on packed arrays, too, if your data happens to be in that form.

Answer (score 4):

```
DeleteCases[data, a_ /; MemberQ[a, Max[data[[All, 4]]]]] // MatrixForm
```

> [image: Blockquote]

Answer (score 3):

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
```

I have modified `data` and added another copy of the maximum entry for testing.

```
data = {{16, 11, 12, 0.002}, {11, 16, 52, 0.052}, {15, 12, 22, 
    0.012}, {14, 13, 22, 0.022}, {13, 14, 32, 0.032}, {12, 15, 42, 
    0.042}, {11, 16, 52, 0.052}};
```

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 16 & 11 & 12 & 0.002 \\
 11 & 16 & 52 & 0.052 \\
 15 & 12 & 22 & 0.012 \\
 14 & 13 & 22 & 0.022 \\
 13 & 14 & 32 & 0.032 \\
 12 & 15 & 42 & 0.042 \\
 11 & 16 & 52 & 0.052 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

```
pos = Position[data[[All, -1]], x_ /; x == Max[data[[All, -1]]]]
```

> {{2}, {7}}

To delete the first one only: use `First@pos` or to delete all entries, use the entire list called `pos`:

```
Delete[data, First@pos] // TableForm
```

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 16 & 11 & 12 & 0.002 \\
 15 & 12 & 22 & 0.012 \\
 14 & 13 & 22 & 0.022 \\
 13 & 14 & 32 & 0.032 \\
 12 & 15 & 42 & 0.042 \\
 11 & 16 & 52 & 0.052 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

---

Using pattern matching: (Instead of `Infinity` use the number of entries to delete)

```
DeleteCases[data, {_, _, _, x_} /; 
  x == Max[data[[All, -1]]], {1}, Infinity]
```

Answer (score 3):

This works if max is unique.

```
Most@SortBy[data,Last]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
data = {
{16, 11, 12, 0.002},
{15, 12, 22, 0.012},
{14, 13, 22, 0.022},
{13, 14, 32, 0.032},
{12, 15, 42, 0.042},
{11, 16, 52, 0.052}
};
```

Since `V 13.2` we have `PositionLargest`

```
MapAt[Nothing, data, List /@ PositionLargest[Last /@ data]]
```

{{16, 11, 12, 0.002}, {15, 12, 22, 0.012}, {14, 13, 22, 0.022}, {13,
14, 32, 0.032}, {12, 15, 42, 0.042}}

If there were multiple elements with the same maximal error one could do f.e.

```
MapAt[Nothing, data, Rest[List /@ PositionLargest[Last /@ data]]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try
`Select[data, #[[-1]] < Max[data[[All, -1]]] &]`

Answer (score 1):

Using `Reap`, `Scan` and `Sow`:

```
Reap[Scan[If[Last[#] != Max[data[[All, -1]]], Sow[#]] &, data]][[2, 1]]
```

[image]